# Is it “the xᵢ’s” or “the xᵢ”?

Tags: grammatical-number

Let *x*<sub>1</sub>, . . . , *x<sub>n</sub>* be a collection of mathematical objects.

When I refer to them, do I have to say *the x<sub>i</sub>’s* or just *the x<sub>i</sub>*?

**Edit:** In this [article](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1944-50-12/S0002-9904-1944-08255-4/S0002-9904-1944-08255-4.pdf) (written by an American mathematician), one can read

> ... is the set of all x's which have the form ...

Comment: I think it may depend on context. In some circumstances "all *x*" may be appropriate.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen this come up in a textbook or paper.  There's always going to be a better, less awkward way to phrase it, although it'll depend on context.

Comment: I think the real problem here is your use of the definite article *the*.  Usually one would say that *xᵢ is always positive*, or perhaps that *all xᵢ are positive*.

Comment: Mathematicians seem to avoid the plural, with construct like `for all _i_, x_i is non-negative.`

Comment: You assign a symbol to the set. **X** = {x1, x2, ..., xn}. You may need to define additional symbols, for instance, you may need to define a symbol for odd indices.

Comment: You've defined `i` to be a variable, so you'd normally say `x_i for i=1, 2, ..., n`, or `for each x_i` if you've already bound `i` to a range.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting question.  The notation xᵢ refers to all the x's, so it should be taken as plural.  I think if you find a math book, you'll find things like "... the xᵢ are all positive".

Comment: I don’t think that you can use *the* there.

Comment: Such that x subscript i is positive.

Comment: @G. Rem: You can cut-&-paste, and I'll delete: Such that xᵢ is positive.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth The answer to the universe isn't a loaded question.  As such, it's too short to post up here.  But, I will say that it's about relating all the physical quantities in five simple steps while, at the same time, working the mathematical theory of everything in which all numerals thus instantly align.  I know this because, yesterday, after forty years of staring at the same puzzle, I found the five steps.

Comment: @G. Rem
 Replacing 'x subscript i is positive' with 'xᵢ is positive' seems simpler.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth No, because if you write it out, listen to what your saying, then you couldn't end up with wondering that the x subscript i's are positive.  It's not x subscript i's, but x subscript i.  Simple is what remains simple.  So the truly underlying problem in and with science that it can't remain simple because it demands that we renounce our faith (in first principles).  Science seeks an end to itself, but, lacks a means to define infinity.  We will be infinitely smart only at t subscript infinity.  If you want a soluble theory of everything, then begin with a such form of it.

Answer (score 0):

> When I refer to them, do I have to say the xi’s or just the xi?

No x<sub>i</sub>...x<sub>n</sub> is the set of x

> ... is the set of all x's which have the form ...

might be clearer as

... is the set of x in which x has the form ...